# Adding Date to Bash Command - passing a JSON string with shell expansions as part of a URL

Tags: bash, string-interpolation, quoting

I have a simple script:

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
COUNT=`wget -q0- 'https://url.com/query?q={"query_string":"helloworld","date":"$DATE 00:00:00"}'`
echo $COUNT
```

When doing it like this, the API doesn't recognize `$DATE`, however when I replace `$DATE` with the date (2016-10-20), it works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am using backquotes to save to a variable --- it works just fine unless I have a $DATE in there (i put the backquotes in the above example, it just doesn't want to render on the post.

Comment: The above fragment works fine for me. The rendered date is used in the `wget` call. Can you say a iittle more about your environment? How about the output of the above? What exactly goes over the wire?

Comment: Right, so from what I can figure, the wget command is fine, however the application for some reason doesn't want to recognize it.  Basically, it is sending a GET command in JSON format to a web API.  Like I said, if I just manually put in the date rather than using the command, it works like a charm.  What would the difference be between me manually typing 2016-10-20 instead of using $DATE?   Does it mark it as a different string type or add additional characters which the web application may not recognize?

Comment: The `wget` command is not fine, due to quote removal - what you're sending is not valid JSON - at least based on your posted code. If the posted code is what your'e actually using, my answer should provide the solution. If it is not, please post the actual code - ideally, an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - and, in the future, please do so from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted, the shell *does* expand `$DATE`, but it also performs [**quote removal**](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting), which means that `wget` sees something like the following as the URL:

```
https://url.com/query?q={query_string:helloworld,date:2016-10-20 00:00:00} # !! missing "s
```

As you can see, the double quotes are lost; to preserve them, **enclose the entire URL in double quotes and `\`-escape the embedded ones** that JSON requires:

```
date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
count=$(wget -q0- "https://url.com/query?q={\"query_string\":\"helloworld\",\"date\":\"$date 00:00:00\"}")
echo "$count"
```

Now, `wget` sees something like this, as intended:

```
https://url.com/query?q={"query_string":"helloworld","date":"2016-10-20 00:00:00"}
```

Note:

- While `` `...` `` still works for command substitution, it's better to get in the habit of using its modern successor, `$(...)` - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082
- I've changed the variables names, because it is better not to use all-uppercase shell-variable names in order to [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).
- The shell performs expansions only in *double*-quoted strings, whereas *single*-quoted strings are for *literals*.
  [heemayl's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40162375/45375) since-deleted answer demonstrated an alternative to using a single double-quoted string with embedded `\"`s: sandwiching an expandable double-quoted string between two single-quoted literals: `"I am \"$HOME\"."` vs. `'I am "'"$HOME"'".'`